# Pass the context from a fragment inside an activity to another class

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio

I have a fragment which is instantiated by an Activity. The issue that I'm having is that I have another class in the fragment which takes as a parameter an Activity context.

```
public class LocationQueries {
    Activity context;

    private static int REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_PLAY_SERVICES = 200;

    public LocationQueries(Activity context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public boolean checkGooglePlayServices() {

        int checkGooglePlayServices = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context);
        if (checkGooglePlayServices != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
              /*
               * google play services is missing or update is required
               *  return code could be
               * SUCCESS,
               * SERVICE_MISSING, SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED,
               * SERVICE_DISABLED, SERVICE_INVALID.
               */
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(checkGooglePlayServices,
                    context, REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_PLAY_SERVICES).show();

            return false;
        }

        return true;

    }
}
```

I instantiate that class in my fragment like this

```
private LocationQueries locationQueries = new LocationQueries(getActivity());
```

but when I try to use `locationQueries.checkGooglePlayServices();`

I get `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method android.content.pm.PackageManager android.content.Context.getPackageManager() on a null object reference`.
It looks like the `LocationQueries(getActivity())` doesn't actually pass the activity context. How can I solve this ?

Edit: Everything is working if I do the same from an Activity -> `LocationQueries(this);`

Comment: Your Fragment may not yet have attached to the Activity depending at what part of the lifecycle it is in.  As such, it may, in fact, return null.  Make sure to do what you need in between onAttach(Activity) and onDetach()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you initiate `LocationQueries` at the wrong place. Indeed, I assume this:

```
private LocationQueries locationQueries = new LocationQueries(getActivity());
```

is called as a global variable in your `Fragment` class.
Instead you should keep your variable as global but **set it** into `onCreate()` or `onResume()`, as follows:

```
private class Frag extends Fragment {

    private LocationQueries locationQueries;
    ...
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle inState) {
        locationQueries = new LocationQueries(getActivity());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your Fragment appears not to be attached to an Activity.

I suspect you have instantiated your LocationQueries object before onAttach(Activity activity) has been called, or after onDetach() has been called on your Fragment.

In such a case, calling getActivity() will return null which is what you then pass to your LocationQueries object resulting in the NPE.